# How to display fields from JSON blobs in Grafana?

Tags: couchdb, grafana

I'm using the Infinity plugin https://github.com/yesoreyeram/grafana-infinity-datasource/releases .

However I'm trying to get data out of CouchDB, and a database I can't access (over a client's estate). All I have access to is the `find` endpoint. This gives me data of the form:

```json
{
  "clientData": {
    "metric": {
     "Completeness": "75",
     "Timestamp":"2021-09-20T15:21:20",
     "Id":"myID",
     "Validity": "100"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm passing in a selector to the find which will get out the `clientData.metric.Completeness` field, but what I want is to use it in a column, and I don't seem to be able to reference it in Grafana (infinity plugin).

I've tried setting up a row as `clientData.metric.Completeness` and that fails. So currently need a steer on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The Infinity plugin uses JSONPath in the root selector which can be a little tricky to get exactly right.

In your example, you'll want to do something like the following in your query:

Root: `$.clientData.metric`

Column 1: selector `Completeness` as Completeness Number

Here's an easy place to learn and test your JSONPath expressions: https://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 0):

Overall I found the best experience was to actually write the data to an SQL database and use the inbuilt database plugins. This gave me everything I wanted out of the box without using things that were "near-enough" -- after all writing queries in SQL is much better for the client and most "generic" developers.

So the deployment became:

- deploy a database (in our case MySQL, but never mind)
- connect the json api to the database (small amount of rework done here)
- connect Grafana to the database (takes all of 30 seconds)
- write many wonderful queries.

And it's all wrapped up in a docker-compose.